# SQL Command - for multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm having a table with columns - `InvDate`, `CustName`, `InvAmt`, `PayType`, and `PaidAmt`. The amount can be paid by the customer either by Cash, Cheque or Credit Card (`PayType`). 
Now based on this table, I want something like this:

```
SELECT InvDate, CustName, InvAmt, 
       (PaidAmt as CashPay Where PayType = 'Cash'), 
       (PaidAmt as CheqPay WHERE PayType = 'Cheque'), 
       (PaidAmt As CCPay WHERE PayType = "CC') FROM Invoice
```

Comment: Please indicate which form of SQL, ANSI or a specific RDBMs.

Comment: What DB-system are you using? The answer depends on whether you use Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you should be able to *pivot* the data using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression in any database:

```
select invDate, custName, InvAmt,
  sum(case when PayType = 'Cash' then PaidAmt else 0 end) CashPay,
  sum(case when PayType = 'Cheque' then PaidAmt else 0 end) CheqPay,
  sum(case when PayType = 'CC' then PaidAmt else 0 end) CCPay
from Invoice
group by invDate, custName, InvAmt
```

If you are using a database with a `PIVOT` function (SQL Server 2005+/Oracle 11g+), then you can use:

```
select *
from
(
  select invDate, custName, InvAmt,
    PayType, PaidAmt
  from Invoice
) src
pivot
(
  sum(paidamt)
  for paytype in (Cash, Cheque, CC)
) piv
```

There are also ways that this can be done by joining on your table multiple times but you would need to provide additional details about the table structure to properly construct that query.

Comment: Actually I disagree with you. If the customer has more than one invoice per day they most likely want the total in each pay type thus the aggregation is needed.

Comment: @AndersUP You are able to join on the table multiple times, I just don't have time to tet at this moment.

Comment: As a simple follow-up note, first chances are that if you aren't doing aggregates, the accounting db is probably badly designed (I figure I am qualified to say this), and secondly if that's the case, removing the sum and group by portions will be sufficient to pivot the information.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Yes, the original pivot-solution (with or without the aggregation) was valid and within the question, which was why I didn't include a pivot in my answer. But the - now removed - multijoin was incorrectly constructed and could not return a correct answer. bluefeet: I don't dispute that you can join the same table multiple times, but it is a difficult construct here as you have no guarantee that you will have a anchor row so in reality you're looking at a cross join - and then you'd probably be better off with one of the solutions already suggested.

Comment: @AndersUP I removed the multi join because while it is possible to do so, I didn't have time to test the answer and I agree there is not enough details to possibly join the rows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you could write something like:

```
SELECT InvDate, CustName, InvAmt, 
       CASE WHEN PayType = 'Cash' THEN PaidAmt ELSE 0 END CashPay,
       CASE WHEN PayType = 'Cheque' THEN PaidAmt ELSE 0 END CheqPay,
       CASE WHEN PayType = 'CC' THEN PaidAmt ELSE 0 END CCPay
FROM Invoice
```

Comment: I thought you initially had an aggregate function on your answer thus my comment. I removed my comment when I saw you didn't.  But just because I commented on your answer doesn't warrant a downvote of mine.

Comment: Just to clarify, I DID NOT DOWNVOTE your answer. I commented on your post which I removed my comment once I realized that my comment was incorrect.  I disagree with you that you say that my answer will provide an incorrect result. All 3 versions (yours/mine) provide the identical result -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3556d/5

Comment: My downvote has been removed as it was aimed at the join, not the two other solutions. I agree that the current three versions provide valid results.